# How to prevent negative integer treated as shorthand flag

Tags: go, go-cobra

I need to parse command line args containing negative ints, spf13/cobra is the library of choice:

```
go run main.go write -d 1 -a mock -e int 0 2 -1
```

Unfortunately cobra thinks that `-1` is a shorthand flag which is of course not defined:

```
Error: unknown shorthand flag: '1' in -1
```

I've tried single and double quotest around `-1` with same result. How can I have cobra leave negative ints as args instead of flags?

Comment: `go run main.go write -d 1 -a mock -e int -- 0 2 -1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as expected: it's impossible to distinguish between arguments and flags.

It's the caller responsibility to make it unambiguous using `--`:

```
go run main.go write -d 1 -a mock -e int -- 0 2 -1
```

`--` means "whatever comes after these dashes are arguments"

References:

- https://github.com/spf13/cobra/issues/124